# Actionscript - How to import swf with an html wrapper to timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3

Afternoon,

I have a multiple choice quiz generated by a third party software which can export the quiz as an swf file.

The swf file comes with an html wrapper.(index.html)
It also creates a data folder that has a javascript file. No fla file is given.

My problem is...I'm working with flash cc to create a navigation menu so you click a button a video plays..then at the end of video you click and you take the quiz.

I am able to have the video stop and assign a click to it...What do i need to do to have the button call the swf file(when imported by itself comes up blank) or the index.html so the quiz will show up inside the timeline of the fla that i am working with?

I'm making a free training DVD for my students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class `Loader`:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.swf");
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false,ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
loader.load(url, loaderContext);
```

When it's finished load, you can use it in you own actionscript file

Comment: Holly cow! I think that worked. I read about the loader class after your post and added: addChild(loader); Now, once the video finishes it displays the swf quiz. My hero!